# Passing Parameter to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going to create a controller that will list distinct a selected field in a selected table in database and pass it to my API.

Currently, i am using a dirty method which is create several controller that has the field name and table name in it.

**controller.js**

```
.controller('ListDistinctCustomerCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var xhr = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/api/list-distinct.php?table=customer&field=cust_code'
  });
  xhr.success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data.data;
  });
})

.controller('ListDistinctSupplierCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var xhr = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/api/list-distinct.php?table=supplier&field=supp_code'
  });
  xhr.success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data.data;
  });
})
```

and this is the API file

**list-distinct.php**

```
<?php
require_once '/config/dbconfig.php';
$table = $_GET['table'];
$field = $_GET['field'];
GetData($table,$field);

function GetData($tablename,$fieldname) {
    $sql = "SELECT distinct $fieldname as expr1 FROM $tablename order by expr1 asc";
    try {
        $db = getdb();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
?>
```

I believe there is a clean and better way to do this.

Comment: Maybe create an API `service` so you don't have the duplicate code

Comment: What is your question? Cleaner JS or PHP?

Comment: You should *not* parse your GET params directly into your SQL query. Expecialy not for `field` / `table`. Kind of big security lag.

Comment: @Ties cleaner angular way. @lin is it by adding `mysqli_real_escape_string` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service which contains methods for accessing your API.  This will enable you to reduce your code duplication in your controllers, and allow for cleaner code in general.

```
.service('APIService', function($http){
    var base = 'http://localhost/api/';
    this.listDistinct = function(table, field){
        return $http({
            method: 'post'
            , url: base + '/list-distinct.php'
            , params: {
                table: table
                , field: field
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Your controllers would inject the service and call whatever method it needs to access the api.  Results will be obtained the same way by attaching a promise callback.

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, APIService){
    APIService.listDistinct('customer', 'cust_code').then(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    })
});
```

For the PHP side of your code you need to use a white-list of possible table/field names to ensure safe operation. Without such a check you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  A simple array check would suffice.

```
$safeTables = ['customer', 'supplier'];
$safeFields = ['cust_code', 'supp_code'];

if (!in_array($tablename, $safeTables) || !in_array($fieldname, $safeFields)){
   throw new Exception('Invalid parameter');
}
```

Comment: is this mean i still have to create multiple controller eg, 1 for the customer and 1 for the supplier?

Comment: No, you could use one controller and just pass the necessary information into the service as the parameters.

Comment: sorry, still not too clear, i have a html with `div` that has a controller in it. lets say i have first `div` that will show the data from customer and the code will be `<div ng-controller="ListDistinct"></div>`, while another div will be display the data from supplier, using same controller it would be `<div ng-controller="ListDistinct"></div>` as well, where i can pass paramaters to get the correct data?

Comment: Use separate controllers if you're doing separate divs on one page.  A single controller could be used if you're using ngRoute by using route parameters.

Comment: okay, thank you for the guidance, i will try to look for the ngRoute

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if you want to pass parameters by $http there is a cleaner method:

```
$http( 
    {
       url: 'your url',
       method: 'GET or POST',
       params: {
         // list of params
       }
    }
);
```

Now, is important for code maintenance and readability to use [Service provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).
You can use Factory as service and create an API service.

Example:

```
angular.module( 'yourModule' ).factory( 'ServiceAPI', [ '$http', function ( $http ) {

var factory = {};

//PUBLIC METHODS
factory.method = method;

function method() {
  return $http( 
           {
               url: 'your url',
               method: 'GET or POST',
               params: {
                 // list of params
               }
           }
        );
}

return factory;
} ] );
```

And now you can inject ServiceAPI on your Controller and use method function that reply with a promise of http.

```
angular.module( 'your module' ).controller( 'Ctrl', [ '$scope', 'ServiceAPI' ,
function ( $scope, ServiceAPI ) {

  ServiceAPI.method.then( function ( data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    }, function(){console.err('error');} );
}
] );
```

AngularJS side, now is clear and readable.

I hope to be helpful for you.
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Its time for [Angular Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

This is an example for your case:

```
angular.module('starter')
.factory('services', services);

function services($http) {
        var services = {
            customer: customer,
            supplier: supplier,
        };
        return services;

        //customer service
        function customer() {
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/api/list-distinct.php?table=customer&field=cust_code',
                headers: {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'contentType': "application/json"
                }
            };
            return $http(req);
        },

       //supplier service
        function supplier() {
            var req = {
                method: 'POST,
                url: 'http://localhost/api/list-distinct.php?table=supplier&field=supp_code',
                headers: {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'contentType': "application/json"
                }
            };
            return $http(req);
        };
 }
```

Then you call them like this from within the controller:

```
services.customer().then(
      function(response) {
      //do whatever is needed with the response
        console.log(response);
      },

      function (error) {
        console.log(error); 
      }
   );




services.supplier().then(
          function(response) {
          //do whatever is needed with the response
            console.log(response);
          },

          function (error) {
            console.log(error); 
          }
        );
```